# Umbraco: Manage hostnames programmatically through the API

Tags: api, umbraco

Does anyone know of a way to manage Hostnames programmatically for Umbraco IContent objects ?

I need to import a whole site from a csv and I need to set the Hostnames from code automatically.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this will help you?

```
var domain = new umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web.Domain("example.com")
                 {
                     RootNodeId = 1078,
                     Language = Language.GetByCultureCode("en-GB"),
                 };
domain.Save();
```

Comment: Billion of thanks @ProNotion. Your code pointed me in the right direction !
I found this method:
`umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web.Domain.MakeNew(name, content.Id, umbraco.cms.businesslogic.language.Language.GetByCultureCode("en-US").id);`

Answer (score 1):

For the Umbraco 6+ API version this might be of some use - this is adapted from existing code - but you should get the gist:

```
    private readonly IDomainService _umbDomainService;
    private readonly ILocalizationService _umbLocalizationService;
```

...

```
        this._umbDomainService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.DomainService;
        this._umbLocalizationService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.LocalizationService;
```

...

```
        //Ensure the language:
        var language = this._umbLocalizationService.GetLanguageByIsoCode(config.CultureInfo.Name);
        if (language == null)
        {
            language = new Language("en-GB");
            language.CultureName = "English UK, not sure used...";
            this._umbLocalizationService.Save(language);
        }

        //TODO: Set the main language on the node...?
        this._umbContentService.Save(rootTarget); //The root node using the domain

        //Set the domain:
        IDomain domain = new UmbracoDomain("www.example.com");
        domain.LanguageId = language.Id;
        domain.RootContentId = rootTarget.Id; //id of root node to apply domain to
        _umbDomainService.Save(domain);
```